# Positioning text against the bottom of a block element

Tags: html

Given the following, how can I place the text `foo` at the bottom of the block `div` element?

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px">foo</div>
```

Comment: Would you be okay with wrapping the text in another element? If not, I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: I'd rather not, but will if I have to.

Answer (score 3):

You add `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom`:

```css
div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px">foo</div>
```

Add another one using `pseudo-elemet` `:before`(height must be equal of div height):

```css
div {
  background: red;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a separate element with:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

And give the parent `position:relative` to establish a new positioning context.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5hLvrsn/).

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with beautiful and modern `flex-box`:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">foo</div>
```

Keep in mind that it's absolutely mandatory to keep styles where their place is:

```
.myDiv {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

I'm aware that **this approach is not 100% supported** but yet another addition to the tons of answers which are about to show up.
Moreover, I wouldn't take IE8 into account those days.

Comment: Do keep in mind that this example will not work in [IE9 at all, nor in IE10 or iOS Safari without prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: What is the actual DOM created by the DOM in the question? The text `foo` creates an implicit text node inside the `div` right? I presume `flex-box` gives us control over this implicit node?

Comment: @Ben: it's just a single element with CDATA, flexbox just controls the way its content is laid out (in this case 'pushed to the vertical end of the container').

Comment: Does the CDATA correspond to a separate node in the DOM tree?

Comment: No, it's not a node, it's a specific element type. Not really on topic here though.

Comment: @Ben As Niels is pointing out, this is CSS which does not affect the DOM at all.

Comment: @Rob, Yes I know. It was a separate question about the resultant DOM.